# Batch file check if file overwrote properly

Tags: batch-file, dos, overwrite, file-comparison

I need to save a file by copying it to a `.bak` in a batch file.

I then need to check if my file overwrote properly the existing `.bak`. Simply comparing the files could not be working, as it is possible for the user to save it twice in a row with no changes.

What I already have is:

```
type carnet.txt > carnet.bak
```

or this which works too:

```
copy carnet.txt carnet.bak
```

But it does not check if the file was really overwrote.

Comment: Chech for error in the operation. You ask the os to copy a file. Trust it will do their work, and if file copy fails errorlevel will be set. Check errorlevel.

Comment: You could use `xcopy` with the `/v` option to verify the size of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 copy carnet.txt carnet.bak
 FC /b carnet.txt  carnet.bak | FIND "FC: no dif" > nul 
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ( echo "files are different" ) else ( echo "successful backup" )
```

[more for FC command](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html)